# Error in Intent - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, vuforia

I'm trying to modify vuforia's sample videoplayback application in Android Studio. In that sample app, video will be played whenever targeted image is focused. I try to modify like I want to go next activity when the video is played fully. So I just used Intent, but it will throw and error as "Cannot resolve constructor Intent". Here I have attached screenshot of the error.Can you guys please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance. 
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Si1x.png) [VideoPlayerHelper imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z951H.png)

Comment: Change like this Intent intent = new Intent(VideoPlayerHelper.this,SearchResult.class);

Comment: Intent doesn't support a constructor with a parameter list of VideoHelper and SearchResult

Comment: `new Intent(VideoPlayerHelper.this,SearchResult.Class)`

Comment: Thanks for your response guys.. 
Intent intent = new Intent(VideoPlayerHelper.this,SearchResult.class) also doesn't work.  Getting same error

Comment: new Intent(VideoPlayerHelper.this,SearchResult.Class). Is **class** not Class.

Comment: @Jonas - Yes I can understand from the error description. Let me know why it is not supported. How to resolve it

Comment: add VideoPlayerHelper and  SearchResults imports here .

Comment: what is VideoPlayerHelper? activity, fragment or just class?

Comment: @PushpendraChoudhary : VideoPlayerHelper is class, SearchResult is Activity

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResult.class);
```

"this" should be context or child's context.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(type of context, SearchResult.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a class you need to pass the context to the class(passing through constructor would be better). Then do following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,SearchResult.class);
```

and better way is create listeners(interface) and call appropriate method on activity using them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Intent intent = new Intent(VideoPlayerHelper.this,SearchResult.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Just change u're coding

> Intent intent = new Intent(this,SearchResult.class);

to

> Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent(),SearchResult.class);